# how to sympy matrix rank nessesary value?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

```py
    from sympy import *
    var('a11 a12 a13 a21 a22 a23 a31 a32 a33')
    print("(1)",
          Matrix([[-1, 1, -1], [2, 0, 1], [1, -3, 2]])
          .rank()
         )
    print("(2)",
          Matrix([[a11,a12,a13],[a21,a22,a23],[a31,a32,a33]])
          .subs({a11:-1,a12:1,a13:-1,a21:2,a22:0,a23:1,a31:1,a32:-3,a33:2})
          .rank()
         )
    print("(3)",
          Matrix([[a11,a12,a13],[a21,a22,a23],[a31,a32,a33]])
          .rank()
         )
    print("(4)",
          Matrix([[a11,a12,a13],[a21,a22,a23],[a31,a32,a33]])
          .rank()
          .subs({a11:-1,a12:1,a13:-1,a21:2,a22:0,a23:1,a31:1,a32:-3,a33:2})
         )
```

(1) 2

(2) 2

why (3) rank=3?

why (4) AttributeError?

File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 17, in 
Matrix([[a11,a12,a13],[a21,a22,a23],[a31,a32,a33]])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'subs'

Comment: When you get an `AttributeError` there 2 possible causes.  Either you read the documentation wrong and are asking for an attribute or method that the object class does not define.  Or the object in the code is not what you intended.  Here I suspect you intended to use `subs` on a sympy expression.  But the item in question is actually a number, an `int`, which obviously does not have a `subs` method.  So you need to figure out why this is a number rather than an `expr`.

Comment: The `rank` method gives the rank of a matrix as an int. If you want to substitute values in to the matrix and then compute the rank then you need to call subs first and rank after.